# JQuery.Validate clean way to check if a ul has at least one li item

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate

In my webpage I have an "AddProduct" form. It has fields for product attributes (name, price, etc...) and I use FineUploader in order to add images. The uploaded images are added as hidden fields in li elements of a list in the form. Basically my html looks like:

```
<form>
<input type="text" value="name" id="name> 
....

<ul>
</ul>

<div id="ulpoader"></div> -> this will add files as <li> elements
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I want to check before submitting the form if the ul has at least a li element (at least an image was added). I use ASP MVC3. Can I add some javascript on client side for adding a new rule to the form?

Edited:
I know how to do the jquery selection ... the thing that I do not know is to integrate that with jquery validate plugin.

Comment: are you using Microsoft's 'unobtrusive' js script as well as jquery validate?

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
if($('ul li').length > 0)
{

}
```

Comment: but how to add this handler to jquery validate plugin to execute before submitting the form?

Comment: can you tell me how to integrate this with jquery validate plugin?

Comment: I think you are submit handler would help you, check it over here, http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($('ul').children('li').length > 0) {
    // your logic
}
```

Comment: can you tell me how to integrate this with jquery validate plugin? Where to add this check?

Comment: in your custom `html` shown above, just add a script tag in such a way 

<script>
$(document.ready(function(){
if ($('ul').children('li').length > 0) {
    // your logic
}
});
</script>

Answer (score 0):

You can also try

```
     if($('ul li').size())
     {

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery Validation library **validates only form fields** (input, select, textarea etc). You cannot check if an ul includes a li with jQuery Validation. You can do it with other ways like the other so users suggested,

```
$("form").validate({
    submitHandler: function (form) {
        if($('ul li').length === 0){
            alert("No li elements!");
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Did you mean if($('ul li').length < 1) :-)